# Server disconnect while returning data from Javascript

Tags: javascript, blazor, blazor-server-side

My Blazor Server app uses a `canvas` element to manipulate an image that is loaded into an `img` element via a file drop zone, it serves as a reference for the canvas and holds the information that is worked on via JS. I'm using Excubo's Canvas wrapper to work within C# as much as possible but I don't think this error is related to it as it also happens with pure JS. Since this is more of a logic problem I don't think sharing code would be much help but here is a crud visual representation of what I mean, perhaps it will be more useful in trying to convey the problem.

[image: Diagram]

The end goal is to invoke a function in JS to load the image `src` into a secondary work canvas, and using the data present in the main canvas, manipulate pixel information accordingly for both. After parsing the data, I convert it back `toDataURL` and set the `img.src` attribute.

The problem happens when returning the base64 data from that function particularly when using large images. The server disconnects immediately and I'm not sure if there is a way to extend the allowed wait time or this is just an implementation problem on my part.

Also worth mentioning that I extended the maximum file size for the dropzone InputFile component to 30MB but this happens with files of 3MB (and maybe even lower but I couldn't troubleshoot the threshold value yet).

Perhaps there's another way to achieve what I'm aiming for but I'm not sure how I would reference the img src attribute in C# without JS. Client-Server side logic isn't a concern because this app is supposed to be run locally on the server machine only so they are essentially the same target.

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution that works for my case. [Here is the reference for the fix.](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/9570#issuecomment-515928994)

The default `MaximumReceiveMessageSize` is too low for my needs, I increased it to 30MB and it works without disconnecting from server. Also tried increasing the `ApplicationMaxBufferSize` and `TransportMaxBufferSize` on the `MapBlazorHub` pipeline configurations but it didn't help. Increasing JS interop timeout on the `AddServerSideBlazor` service options was also unfruitful.

Here is the relevant `Program.cs` code I'm using now:

```cs
var maxBufferSize = 30 * 1024 * 1024;
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddHubOptions(opt => { opt.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = maxBufferSize; });
```